# Ambiguous tag: blocking

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The tag [blocking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/blocking) is ambiguous. It contains stuff about blocking websites, unblocking hardware, email, and more.

I wanted to use it for blocking websites, but given the ambiguity I doubt about it. I ended up using [self-control](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/self-control) as a possible tag for things on putting time restrictions to application use, visiting websites, which websites, and more. I am open for corrections, the tag is not described yet. It also comes quite closely to some stuff under the tag [parental-controls](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/parental-controls).

Comment: Kill it with fire!

Answer (score 4):

There are so many things [blocking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/blocking) can mean, and if we allow this tag to keep existing, it's sure to take on even more mutually unrelated meanings. ([Blocking I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_%28computing%29), ...)

As [Jorge Castro says](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7115/ambiguous-tag-blocking#comment11169_7115), "Kill it with fire!"